# Why i'm unable to call WCF RESTful services on other PC having same ip series

Tags: wcf, iis

I hosted wcf services in IIS and it's working fine everywhere. But, some PC's having same IP config. it showing can't be reached.

Ex: server PC have 10.10.10.10(suppose) IP and other PC have 10.10.10.11. In 2nd pc i'm unable to call API which is hosted in 10.10.10.10. But, in all other pc and network domains working fine.

Please help me regarding this.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, i got it!!!
just added 10.10.10.10 in hosts exception.